# Behavior of cuts with respect to multiplication

Tags: real-analysis

Let x = A|B, x = A'|B' be cuts in $\mathbb{Q}$.

We defined x+x' = (A+A') | rest of $\mathbb{Q}$

Would this work if it was multiplication?

for example x·x' = (A·A')| rest of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Do you mean [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) ?

Comment: Please learn the basics of Latex. For example write `$\mathbb{Q}$` for $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not. For ex, suppose you have two rational cuts, $2^*$ and $3^*$ say. It’s product should be $6^*$. But if you take the product $(-\infty,2)\cdot (-\infty,3)$ (0f rationals only, of course) you get the whole set $\mathbb Q$. To solve the problem, you start by defining the product of positive cuts, taking all possible products of positive elements in $A$ and $A’$ and adding the negatives to get the left half of a cut. Then you define the product in the general case by reducing to that case. For ex if $-x$ and $y$ are positive cuts, you define $x\cdot y$ to be $-((-x)\cdot y)$ etc.

Comment: What would * mean in this instance?

Comment: For a rational $r$, by $r^*$ I represent the cut defining $r$.